# i need to connect my DB form a local Lan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

the below is my connection string which i am using in my solution.
now i need to connect that DB from another machine which is connected via Lan

```
<add name="connectionName" connectionString="server=.;database=dbName;uid=UserID;pwd=userPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146281/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-via-lan

Comment: server=. means your local machine so instead of ".", you need to provide the ip or computer name of your server

Comment: it didt help. i there is an issue related with sql config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your connection string (server=.) to (server=servername) and make sure your server is configured to accept remote connection. (TCP/IP in SQL Server configuration manager is will configured).