# How can i access the sql server into other PC in the local network?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two computer on my local wireless modem network.

```
BEHZAD-PC---->install sql server on it.
AKBAR-PC----->want to access BEHZAD-PC sql server data with c#.
```

and my connection string on `akbar-pc` is:

```
string conn = "Data Source=BEHZAD-PC;Initial Catalog=brilliantit.ir_behitable;Integrated Security=True";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect to sql server database via LAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146281/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-via-lan)

Comment: Are both of the PCs in the same windows domain?

Comment: No,i have a wireless modem,and two pc connect together with this modem

Comment: I don't see any issue with your current connection string. try and see if you can ping both the machine from each other? If yes, then you shouldn't be facing any issue connecting then with your existing con string.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to connect to SQL Server on another machine:

1. Configure SQL Server for remote access. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138172/enable-tcp-ip-remote-connections-to-sql-server-express-already-installed-databas) you can find how to enable TCP/IP connection to SQL Server
2. If you don't use the default port number for TCP/IP protocol with your SQL Server, you may want to see how to pass the port number: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012) (BUT generally I don't think it applies to your case)
3. Be sure whether your SQL Server instance is configured for mixed mode authentication: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393654/how-can-i-change-from-sql-server-windows-mode-to-mixed-mode-sql-server-2008)
4. Make a proper login from **Security->Login**. For simplicity do not check *"Enforce password policy"*, *"Enforce password expiration"* and *"User must change password at next login"* . Then in the **User Mapping** tab get the read/write access for this login to the target database.

Comment: i test your solution and i get this error:Login failed for user 'behzad'

Comment: my connection string is:string conn = "Data Source=BEHZAD-PC;Initial Catalog=brilliantit.ir_behitable;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=behzad;Password=beh1368421;Connect Timeout=300000";

Comment: You should have such login (user=behzad, pass=...) defined in that SQL Server instance which you are going to connect. Moreover you should get the access to the initial catalog for this user.

Comment: i create user=behzad and pass=beh1368421 but i get this message:can not login user 'behzad'

Comment: i create with step by step with your solution but i get this error:TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to BEHZAD-PC.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'RARA'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------

Comment: These are steps: 1. Enable remote connection to sql server 2. Prepare a proper login with read/write access to the target database 3. Make a LAN and connect to the SQL Server using (IP,port) and login informations

Comment: Following Error:18456, there may be another issue. Ensure whether you have enabled Mixed mode authentication on your SQL Server: Right click on the Server->Properties->Security->Check `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode`

Comment: excuse me i am beginner in sql server!,how can i enable remote connection ?database read/write?make lan connect? how can i enable mixed mode?

Comment: thanks for pay attention my problem,when i create a user,and i want to connect my database with this account,in Connect to server windows,whats is ServerName field?is this my pc name?BEHZAD-PC?

Comment: when i enter password in login user define level,i define 1368421 but when i return back i see change the password!

Comment: The server name is the IP address. You see the change the password because you didn't follow the step 4 exactly (You leaved the "User must change password at next login" as checked when defining the login). BUT No problem. simply change the password and use that changed password in connection string

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you have SQL Server Express or not. I suppose you have express version because you are asking this. In this case you have to enable some protocols and start SQL Server Browser service.

look here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165647(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Data Source=IP of your server;Initial Catalog=yourDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=yourUser;Password=yourPassword;Connect Timeout=just a timeout connection
```

Remember a couple of things:

- Open the 1433 port in your server (you can visit a post called: [Firewall Port 1433 not opening](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13304249/771579)
- For other problems visit: [Enable remote connections for SQL Server...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11278114/771579)